# Boolean Masking on pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, boolean, masking

I have multiple columns in a data-frame. I have set a condition for one column and i got a true/false array. Now i want to remove the false row values from that column which will also remove the corresponding row values from the other columns too.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

sample = {
    "COL_1" : [10,45,747,120,45,78],
    "COL_2" : [11,45,78,45,10,25],
    "COL_3" : [44,55,77,50,60,40]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(sample)

mask = df['COL_1']>100
```

Now i want to filter my whole data-frame using the mask array.

Comment: Try `df[mask]` ?

Comment: Thanks . It was actually very simple. I was thinking complex.

Comment: Is there a way to use df[mask] without affecting the resulting size ?